# Is Comptia's Project+ certification respected/respectable?

Tags: certification

What do people think of this certification? Is it something to advertise if you have it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define respected. If you mean on par with a PMP or Prince2, then no, it's not on that level. Not because there's anything inherently 'wrong' with it, but simply because it's not as rigorous as the others, and the requirements to sit of it aren't as stringent.

Think of it as a 'very' entry-level certification. But if you have it, there's certainly no reason not to advertise it.